# for loop - java and Python work differently

Tags: python, for-range

I want to modify variable `y` and it works in Java as below

```
for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
          {
            for(int y=0;y<3;y++)
            {
                System.out.print(y);
                if(y==1){y+=1;}              
            } 
          } // output == 01010101
```

But when I try to implement the same logic in Python it doesn't work as below

```
for x in range(0,4):
    for y in range(0,3):
        print(y, end='')
        if y==1:
            y+=1 # output == 012012012012
```

is there way to modify a variable in inner for-range loop in python?

Comment: You should note that it is considered bad practice to change the value of the iterator (in this case, `y`) inside the for loop.

Comment: In a `for` loop, IMHO the loop variable should only be increased in the `for` part, not in the body. It makes the code hard to understand.

Comment: For more read [The for statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to in C (and Java)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score -1):

This is the code which is working, just change the range of y from `(0, 3)` to `(0, 2)`:

```py
for x in range (0, 4):
    for y in range (0, 2):
        print(y, end = '')
        if y == 1:
            y += 1
```